# Show that if $f$ is an entire function with $Re\,f(z) > M\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, then $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I have the following proof but I don't know if I am right:

$$ \left|\frac{1}{e^{f(z)}}\right| = \left|\frac{1}{e^{Re\,f(z)}}\right| < \left|\frac{1}{e^{M}}\right|$$

Since $1/e^{f(z)}$ is entire, it follows from Liouville's theorem that $1/e^{f(z)}$ is constant.

$\Rightarrow e^{f(z)}$ is constant

$\Rightarrow f'(z)e^{f(z)} = 0 $

$\Rightarrow f'(z)=0$

$\Rightarrow f$ is constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct. A key step is that for any $z$, one has:
$$
|e^z|=|e^{Re(z)}|
$$

Also, $e^z$ is non-zero for any $z$. You applied the chain rule correctly to $e^{f(z)}$.

Comment: ... and the modulus is useless for $e^{\mathrm{Re}(z)}$.